# X509 Cannot find requested object

Tags: c#, x509certificate, x509

I have a certificate.cer file in the same directory (copy if newer) with the RSA key inside yet when I try:

```
string certificateFile = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Certificate.cer";
X509Certificate2 x509 = new X509Certificate2(X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(certificateFile));
```

I get the same

> *"Cannot find requested object"*

error. How can I not get the error?

Comment: What do you get if you check the value of certificateFile after setting it?

Answer (score 2):

You can just pass the filename into the new() method.

Try:

```
X509Certificate2 x509 = new X509Certificate2(certificateFile);
```

If the certificate has a password, you must also supply this (where `password` is a String):

```
X509Certificate2 x509 = new X509Certificate2(certificateFile, password);
```

Comment: How could you parse a certificate if you have the bytes in a variable, not a file?